# Finding the integral without knowing the actual equation, but some several information is given.

Tags: calculus, integration

For any real number x, $f(x) = f(x + 2)$.

Let $f(x) = -x^2 + 2, -1 \le x \le  1$

I need to compute: $$\int_{-1}^6 f(x) \,dx$$

I came up with the idea that I might split the range $(-1, 6)$ to its components. Like:

$$\int_{-1}^6 f(x) \,dx = \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \,dx + \int_{1}^6 f(x) \,dx$$

By this action, we can figure out the 1st term, but I have no idea what to do with the 2nd term. I am stuck, could you please help me to complete with this idea, or if you have your own approach that is welcomed too.

Comment: You can integrate the function between -1 and 1 since you know the formula explicitly. Since it is periodic, you can integrate it in the desired interval.

Comment: Let $$~A = \int_{-1}^6 f(x)dx,~B = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx, ~C = \int_{-1}^0 f(x)dx.$$  Then, both $B$ and $C$ are directly computable, from the specification, while $A = 3B + C$, given that $f(x)$ is periodic, with a period of $2$.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you so much. It worked well.

Comment: @VECH thank you too

Answer (score 2):

For any real number $\ x,\ f(x) = f(x + 2).\ $ Then use for example,

$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) \,dx = \int_{1}^3 f(x) \,dx = \int_{3}^5 f(x) \,dx,$$

and

$$\int_{-1}^6 f(x) \,dx = \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \,dx + \int_{1}^3 f(x) \,dx + \int_{3}^5 f(x) \,dx + \int_{5}^6 f(x) \,dx$$